# Pass flags to the Sphinx runner?

Tags: read-the-docs

So I've got the following project [OpenFHE-development](https://readthedocs.org/projects/openfhe-development/builds/16469588/) and when I run the build process, there are lots of warnings. However, most of these warnings are fine to ignore (we vet them before pushing to the main branch)

Specifically, is there a way to take

```
pth/python -m sphinx -T -E -b readthedocssinglehtmllocalmedia -d _build/doctrees -D language=en . _build/localmedia
```

and convert it to

```
pth/python -m sphinx -T -E -b readthedocssinglehtmllocalmedia -d _build/doctrees -D language=en . _build/localmedia 2> errors.txt
```

(pipe the stderr to a file instead of having it display on stdout)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not seem to be possible at the moment. See [git discussion](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/9043)